# When trying to connect to Salesforce Case Push Topic using Salesforce Kafka Connector getting Error

Tags: apache-kafka, salesforce, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

When object is set as 'Case' instead of the default 'Lead' in  salesforce-example.properties the connect stand alone gives the following error.

```
ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=salesforce-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:177)
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Field type 'location' for field 'pkbgeolocalization__c' is not supported
    at io.confluent.salesforce.common.SObjectHelper.schema(SObjectHelper.java:165)
    at io.confluent.salesforce.common.SObjectHelper.valueSchema(SObjectHelper.java:188)
    at io.confluent.salesforce.pushtopic.SalesforcePushTopicSourceTask.createTopicChannelMessageListener(SalesforcePushTopicSourceTask.java:59)
    at io.confluent.salesforce.common.AbstractSalesforceSourceTask.authenticateAndHanshake(AbstractSalesforceSourceTask.java:211)
    at io.confluent.salesforce.common.AbstractSalesforceSourceTask.start(AbstractSalesforceSourceTask.java:249)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:199)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

"salesforce.object=Case"

Config:

```
name=salesforce tasks.max=1 
connector.class=io.confluent.salesforce.SalesforceSourceConnector 
salesforce.instance=http://test.salesforce.com 
salesforce.username=xxxx 
salesforce.password=**** 
salesforce.password.token=**** 
salesforce.consumer.key=**** 
salesforce.consumer.secret=**** 
salesforce.push.topic.create=false 
salesforce.object=Case 
salesforce.push.topic.name=updates 
kafka.topic=salesforce_updates 
curl.logging=false 
confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092 
confluent.topic.replication.factor=1
```

Comment: Can you share your full connector config please? And what version are you using?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Please find the connector config 
`name=salesforce
tasks.max=1
connector.class=io.confluent.salesforce.SalesforceSourceConnector
salesforce.instance=http://test.salesforce.com
salesforce.username=xxxx
salesforce.password=****
salesforce.password.token=****
salesforce.consumer.key=****
salesforce.consumer.secret=****
salesforce.push.topic.create=false
salesforce.object=Case
salesforce.push.topic.name=updates
kafka.topic=salesforce_updates
curl.logging=false
confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
confluent.topic.replication.factor=1`

Comment: Thanks. I've edited your question to include the config.